# I want to process a recieved message only on 1 fragment at a time

Tags: android, android-fragments, sms

I have 2 fragments in my activity. I am using a Tab View. I am facing the problem that, whenever I am receiving the message, only 2nd fragment is processing that message instead of the first one. Is there any way to force only the current fragment to process the message?

Code for the MessageChecker service:

```
public class MessageChecker extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static MessageListener mListener;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle data = intent.getExtras();
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) data.get("pdus");
        for(int i=0; i<pdus.length; i++){
            SmsMessage smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
            String message = smsMessage.getMessageBody();
            mListener.messageReceived(message);
        }
    }

    public static void bindListener(MessageListener listener){
        mListener = listener;
    }
}
```

Code for my application manifest:

```
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessageService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <activity android:name=".Gateman_Transmition" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".MessageChecker">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>
```

Answer (score 1):

For reviving message on particular fragment.
1- you can initialize BroadcastReceiver locally for example

```
   mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            if (intent.getAction().equals(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION)) {
                // new push notification is received

                String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");

            }
        }
    };
```

2- And register unregistered on the following events.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {

        // by doing this, the activity will be notified each time a new message 
arrives
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver,
                new IntentFilter(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION));

    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {

      LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getContext()).unregisterReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver);
      super.onPause();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by myself by simply adding the listener to fragment class in an button corresponding to specific task of each fragment.

Thanks for the help!!